# How to reverse the arrows in a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a directed graph for which I want to reverse the direction of the arrows (not the direction of edges). I don't want to use `ReverseGraph` because it changes the layout of the graph. Can I achieve this changing `EdgeStyle`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
g1 = Graph[{1 -> 3, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 6, 1 -> 5, 5 -> 4, 6 -> 1}]
```

[image]

#### 1. [`EdgeStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeStyle.html)

```
Graph[g1, EdgeStyle-> Arrowheads[{-.05,0}]]
```

[image]

#### 2. [`EdgeShapeFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeShapeFunction.html)

```
Graph[g1, EdgeShapeFunction -> (Arrow @ Reverse @ # &)]
```

[image]

#### 3. [`ReverseGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReverseGraph.html) + `VertexCoordinates`:

You can also use `ReverseGraph` and keep the vertex layout of `g1`:

```
ReverseGraph[g1, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[g1]]
```

[image]